# Can't resolve module clarifai-nodejs-grpc in React JS

Tags: reactjs, grpc-node, clarifai

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUxzD.jpg)

```
Module not found
Can't resolve 'clarifai-nodejs-grpc' node module grps-js and proto-loader
```

I tried config-overrides.js with react-app-rewired:

```
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  console.log("override");
  let loaders = config.resolve;

  loaders.fallback = {
    fs: false,
    tls: false,
    net: false,
    http: require.resolve("stream-http"),
    https: false,
    zlib: require.resolve("browserify-zlib"),
    path: require.resolve("path-browserify"),
    stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
    url: false,
    util: false,
    http2: false,
    os: false,
    dns: false,
    assert: false,
    buffer: false,
  };

  config.ignoreWarnings = \\\[/Failed to parse source map/\\\];
  return config;
};
```

What can be wrong with this? Why `clarifai-nodejs-grpc` is invisible?

Comment: Try deleting node_modules and reinstalling the package.

Answer (score 0):

If using ReactJS with the Clarifai API, it's recommended you consume it via the JavaScript HTTP channel. You can check the JavaScript samples on their docs platform. The Node gRPC client is recommended for Node.js projects.